# RSpec Request Spec - missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm getting an error when running my tests that I can't quite figure out.

```
#The error
Failure/Error: get post_path, {id: 1}
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Below is the spec.

```
#spec/requests/visitor_interaction_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Visitor', :type => :request do
  context 'following a post link' do
    it 'should redirect to the post' do
      get post_path, {id: 1}
      expect(response).to render_template(:show)
    end
  end
end
```

If I replace `get post_path, {id: 1}` with `get "posts/1"` then the test passes as expected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a non-controller rspec you do it with a uri, but then you'd need to pass the parameter to the path

```
get post_path('1')
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! I tried the first option but got an ArgumentError `bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)`. The second option did the trick though.

Comment: I'd like to understand why passing the id in a params hash isn't working. If you can offer any insight into this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: it's because the test is not a controller test the rspec context would normally reference the controller... then you could call the post action with a symbol and you can specify parameters.  A get outside a controller test only expects URI and the parameters become  `posts/?id='1'` instead of `posts/1`

RSpec.describe PostsController do;
  describe "GET post" do;
    it "renders the post" do;
      post = Post.create;
      get :show, id: post.id;
      expect(response).to render_template(:show);
    end;
  end;
end

see this...
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Comment: Thanks again! This was really helpful. I owe you your drink of choice.

Comment: I have a craving for a cup of tea. How sad is that?